# How to Check dependency service is working or not, before consume the message in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

1. In my application i generate the pdf and send email using
   ActiveMQ.(i.e application never wait for pdf generation, it will put
   the message into queue after that my consumer application get the
   message from queue and create pdf then send it to customer).
2. my application built on top of spring-framework
3. i need to stamp the digital signature in my pdf, if the third party digital-signature server is down, i don't want my consumer to take
   message for queue.
4. if any possibility to add dependency in consumer before consume message

Comment: try Circuit Breaker pattern  ...https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario is a textbook use case for using consumer-side transactions with enterprise messaging. Use the SESSION_TRANSACTED or ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE mode in the session. This allows you to roll the message back to the broker in the event the downstream system is down. You can add delays or retries within your consumer program, and only acknowledge the message when you know its been sent to the other system.

ref: http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-transactions-work.html

Circuit break won't help you if your reliable() path is down as well.